# How do refactor a code which picks service based on null checks on field?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, solid

I have a bean that has around 10+ fields and it may grow till 30 odd fields. The bean is a contract between applications to share data over an HTTP call. Basically, a **downstream application will set exactly one field** and will make a rest call.

```
class Person {
    private PersonalInfo personalInfo;
    private EducationDetails educationDetails;
    private WorkAddressDetails workAddressDetails;    
     ...
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now in my application, I am finding a null field and calling the respective service to process the data.

```
if(personalInfo != null) {
    personalInfoHandler.process(personalInfo);
} else if(educationDetails != null) {
    educationDetailsHandler.process(educationDetails)
} else if(workAddressDetails != null) {
    workAddressDetailsHandler.process(workAddressDetails)
}
...
```

This solution was working fairly well when there were a handful of fields in the bean, now as the bean is growing this solution isn't scaling well. is there a better way to re-design this solution? Initially, I thought about creating a factory of handlers but retrieving the exact type of handler from the factory would be tricky too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bean with 30+ fields, only one of which can be set, and none of whom are very related, seems awkward.

Would it be possible to have each of the fields classes know how to process itself?  e.g. in Java syntax (with a lot of loose ends)

```
interface CanProcess {
  void process(some arguments);
}

class PersonalInfo implements CanProcess {
  void process(some arguments) {
     // implementation, e.g.
     personalInfoHandler.process(this);
  }
}

class EducationDetails implements CanProcess {

  void setCanProcessHandler(CanProcess useThisHandler) {
    this.CPHandler = useThisHandler;
  }

  void process(some arguments) {
    this.CPHandler.process(this);
  }
}
```

Then you can completely eliminate the bean, and just pass around a `CanProcess` and use polymorphism.

Note that, for separation of concerns, the actual implementation of `process()` might internally call a separate helper, such as `personalInfoHandler`, `educationDetailsHandler`, etc...  As illustrated in the code for `PersonalInfo.process()`.

In response to the excellent @candied_orange comment about how to construct the field -> handler linkage:

1. Have it hard coded in the various `CanProcess` instances. (simplest but least robust, as shown in `PersonalInfo` code above)
2. Dependency Inject it, *e.g.*  (shown in `EducationDetails` code above)
   `myCanProcess.setCanProcessHandler(CanProcess useThisHandler);`
3. Use some sort of table lookup or factory, *e.g.*
   `handlerTableLookerUpper.getHanderFor(myCanProcess.class);`

Comment: I suspect polymorphism can help here downstream but before that, where the fields were being set, you need to solve the construction problem that chooses handlers and sets up the polymorphism to work.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant, but I cannot modify the bean as it's present in the library.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare   Which classes do you control and are allowed to edit?

Comment: @lennon310 Thanks for the edits

Comment: @user949300 I don't have control over `Person` and its fields PersonalInfo, EducationDetails, etc.

Comment: @GovindaSakhare Hmm.  Talking from a Java perspective, you _could_ use Reflection to look over all the fields of **Person** to find those that are non-null, then use some sort of Factory or lookup table configured by Spring (or similar) to determine how to `process()`.  But I don't see this as any simpler than your original bunch of `if-else` statements.  More complex in fact.  Only if you prefer programming in XML to Java, or if there are dependency configuration problems, would it make any sense.